# Angular cтилизация <select> и <option>

Tags: html, css, typescript, html-select, angular

Нужно стилизовать `select` и `option` по возможности не меняя стуктуры HTML. Это можно как-то сделать не использую плагины вроде `ng2-select` и подобных? Для них нужно менять HTML и мне это не совсем подходит. Возможно есть какие-то плагины которые позволять стилизовать не изменяя HTML?

Сейчас используются нативный `select`

```
<select  name="name"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedName" #nameCompany="ngModel">
 <option  *ngFor="let name of names" [ngValue]="test">
 {{.name}}
 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: option не стилизуются в принципе. select прячут и показывают вместо него что-то другое + скрипты

Comment: Нативный `select` довольно "дубовый". Возможности его стилизовать очень ограниченны. Но всё-таки определённая свобода есть. Что именно вам надо? Как контретно вы хотите стилизовать ваши выпадающие списки?

Answer (score -1):

"плагины которые позволять стилизовать не изменяя HTML" называются CSS и по определению поддерживаются всеми браузерами.

У вас есть несколько путей.

1. обстилить просто селекты и опшены.
2. обстилить что-нибудь еще и подложить под селект, которому задать прозрачные цвета.

Comment: Возможности стилизации <select> и <option>  c помощью CSS удручающе малы. Если с <select> мы можем как-то работать , то с <option>  почти никак. Единтсвенный вариант использовать JS.   Конечно я мог бы заменить  select,  но вопрос был как обойтись без этого.  Обойтись не получилось, был использован ng2-select

Comment: Вопрос стоял о стилизации селектов и опшенов БЕЗ плагинов и не меняя Html. Если не менять HTML, то и скрипт никакой вам не поможет. А значит, CSS. И за что минуснули, получается, мой ответ?

Comment: А как вы  c пощью CSS будете стилизовать select и option.  select возможно, option практически нет.   Покажите пример, я с радостью признаю себя неправым

Comment: пожалуйста:
http://jsfiddle.net/mf38ueg5/2/